# How to use PHP curl_multi_init() usage when I need to pass a custom options?

Tags: php, curl, remote-server

I have a custom cURL function that has to download huge number of images from remote server. I was banned a couple of times before when I used file_get_contents(). I found that curl_multi_init() is better option as with 1 connection it can download for example 20 images at once.
I made a custom functions that uses curl_init() and I am trying to figure out how I can implement curl_multi_init() so in my LOOP where I grab the list of 20 URLs from the database I can call my custom function and at the last loop to use curl_close(). At the current situation my function generates connection for each url in the LOOP. Here is the function:

```
function downloadUrlToFile($remoteurl,$newfileName){
$errors = 0;
    $options = array(
      CURLOPT_FILE    => fopen('../images/products/'.$newfileName, 'w'),
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT =>  28800,
      CURLOPT_URL     => $remoteurl,
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
    $imageString =curl_exec($ch);
    $image = imagecreatefromstring($imageString);
    if($imageString !== false AND !empty($imageString)){
    if ($image !== false){
        $width_orig = imagesx($image);
        if($width_orig > 1000){
        $saveimage = copy_and_resize_remote_image_product($image,$newfileName);
        }else $saveimage = file_put_contents('../images/products/'.$newfileName,$imageString);
        
        }else $errors++;
    }else $errors++;
    curl_close($ch);
    return $errors;
}
```

There has to be a way to use curl_multi_init() and my function downloadUrlToFile because:

1. I need to change the file name on the fly
2. In my function I am also checking several things for the remote image.. In the sample function I check the size only and resize it if neccessary but there is much more things done by this function (I cutted that part for shorter, but I also use the function to pass more variables..)

How should the code be changed so during the LOOP to connect only once to the remote server?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try this pattern for Multi CURL

```
$urls = array($url_1, $url_2, $url_3);
$content = array();

$ch = array();
$mh = curl_multi_init();

foreach( $urls as $index => $url ) {
    $ch[$index] = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch[$index], CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch[$index], CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch[$index], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch[$index]);
}

$active = null;
for(;;) {
    curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
    if($active < 1){
        // all downloads completed
        break;
    }else{
        // sleep-wait for more data to arrive on socket.
        // (without this, we would be wasting 100% cpu of 1 core while downloading,
        // with this, we'll be using like 1-2% cpu of 1 core instead.)
        curl_multi_select($mh, 1);
    }
}

foreach ( $ch AS $index => $c ) {

    $content[$index] = curl_multi_getcontent($c);
    curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $c);

    //You can add some functions here and use $content[$index]
}

curl_multi_close($mh);
```

Comment: #Alexander, thanks for your time. This was my first approach when I discovered that with similar code I am unable to pass several variables I need. If I could than this code may work for me but.. For example I need to pass: product_id, product_name, product_code.. In my example function I am only showing the product name but I explained that there are more variables I sent actually

Comment: don't use a busyloop; that will waste 100% cpu (of 1 cpu core) for no good reason. instead try: ```for(;;){curl_multi_exec($mh,$active);if($active<1){/*all downloads completed*/break;}curl_multi_select($mh,1);}``` - it will use way less cpu, and be no slower. (seriously if you have a single-core AWS instance, your code will use 100% cpu until everything is downloaded. add a select() in there and it will use like 1-2% cpu until everything is downloaded instead.)

Comment: #hanshenrik what is busyloop? Was this comment for Alexander's answer?

Comment: @Europeuser you can read about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting), there was an issue with Alexander's original code, where it would use something like 98% more cpu than actually needed. but nevermind that, the code is updated, that issue is fixed :)